# Linux max_cstates and idle boot options in ARM processors

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, real-time, intel

Recently, when we changed the platform from an Intel Core2 Duo (2 cores):

```
Kontron Embedded Computers KISS PCI-760 2U
SMP 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz 3000MHz (6144KB cache) 3883 MB memory
```

to an Intel Core i5 (4 cores):

```
Kontron AG KISS PCI-762 2U
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3550S CPU @ 3.00GHz 2993MHz (6144KB cache) 3838 MB memory
```

These systems are running Scientific Linux CERN release 6.6 with the RT_PREEMPT patch:

```
Scientific Linux CERN SLC release 6.6 (Carbon)
Linux 3.6.11-rt30.25.el6rt.x86_64 x86_64
```

After the change, we observed a degradation of the interrupt latency from around 10us to more than 100us with outliers up to 1ms. Where the interrupt latencies were measured with specialized hardware allowing a time accuracy of the order of 1us.

We are pretty sure about this measurements, and in fact, the measurements also agreed with the degradation on the latency between the time a packet is sent and received between two synchronized devices at the ~1us level (using external hardware).

The problem was solved (returning to the same baseline of ~10us latency) by changing to the following Linux boot options on a Scientific Linux 6.6:

```
 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=0 idle=halt
```

You can find an explanation at https://access.redhat.com/articles/65410

The question is: Are the above parameters valid on ARM processors? Where can I find some documentation?

**EDIT**

Considering @Notlikethat comment, I measured the latency using [cyclictest](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cyclictest). On the i5 and Intel Code Duo2 processor using the SLC 6.6 with the RT_PREEMPT patch (and cstate and idle options above), I get a maximum latency of 16us while  using the 4 cores. This measurment is consistent with the one performed with specialized hardware.

While on an ARM Cortex A7 runing Linux alarmpi 4.0.8-3-rt6-ARCH, I get a maximum latency of 136us.

Note that both Intel Core Duo2 and i5 have a similar latency, while the ARM Cortex A7 has 10 times more.

My questions are:

- Is there something to be tuned on the ARM processors under Linux to improve the latency (in addition to setting /dev/cpu_dma_latency to 0us)?
- Where the difference comes from?

Thanks,

Comment: This is hardly my field of expertise, but I would note that idle states are typically controlled entirely in software on ARM-based chips, as opposed to x86 with its automagical hardware control, so picking a fixed "do-nothing" governor (or even compiling idle out altogether) is normally all it takes to remove it from the equation. It would be better to describe the specific latency issues you've observed on ARM, since the architectural differences make it a bit of an apples-to-oranges comparison otherwise.

Comment: ARM Cortex A7 alone does not tell much. Which SoC are you interested in? Also if you are interested in having minimal latencies for a single(or few known) interrupt(s) then you may want to play around with cpu-affinities of individual interrupts on the system to have dedicated cpu-cores to handle the high-prioroty interrupts immediately i.e. extremely low latencies.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: The question already took into account the affinity and priority issues. So, the additional latency of the ARMs with respect to the Intel processors should be related to something else.

Comment: @marcmagransdeabril OK. Next step, ignoring the cpu-affinity/priority for the moment, can you please elaborate a bit upon the latency measurement described in the question. Does it account for ARM being underpowered compared to x86? In other words, does the latency being measured also included the additional time taken by a slower ARM Cortex A7 (compared to an Intel i5) to execute the software stack responsible for preparing and send off the packet? OR is it purely the time taken between TX-ISR function and RX-ISR function on 2 different devices in running in sync?...

Comment: By the way, here is a [list of platforms on which PREEMPT_RT was tested](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_Patch#Platforms_Tested_and_in_Use_with_CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT). The typical default latencies of ARM vs. x86 seem to match your observations of 10x increase from x86 to ARM.